# Detecting changes to checkboxes via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Following on from my previous question.

A requirement from the customer is to have checkboxes on a report to disable rows of information on another sheet. The rows are defined as named ranges, formated by P_XXXXXX. The XXXXXX is a unique identifier that is also a field on the row so I can easily generate the range names on the fly.

The problem I am having is:

- After clicking on the items and then closing the form Excel asks if we want to save. This is undersirable.

I need someway of registering a change event happening on my generated checkboxes. So if one or more changes I can run through and hide/unhide the relevant ranges.

My code for adding the checkboxes looks like:

```
        ' For each row...

        ' check box in column 17(=Q).
        Dim lCenter As Long
        lCenter = rngCurrent.Width / 4 ' not actual centre but close enough
        With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(rngCurrent.Left + lCenter, rngCurrent.Top - 2, rngCurrent.Width, rngCurrent.Height)
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            .Caption = ""
        End With
```

**So how do you link a change in a checkbox with a sub/function?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the OnAction property of the Checkboxes object to the name of a sub you want to run whenever the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

```
Sub MakeCB()

    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(ActiveCell.Left + 0, ActiveCell.Top - 2, ActiveCell.Width, ActiveCell.Height)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        .Caption = ""
        .OnAction = "CheckboxChange"
    End With

End Sub

Sub CheckboxChange()

    MsgBox "change"

End Sub
```

Comment: I placed the CheckboxChange() in both the module and the sheet codebehind but both give me the error "Cannot run the macro 'ent_cc_new_pb.xls!CheckboxChange'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled'. However on opening the workbook it gives me the option to enable macros which I agree to. Any ideas?

Comment: Both subs above would go in a standard module.

From excel with your workbook active, press Alt+F8 to bring up the macro dialog box.  Change the 'Macro in' drop down to This Workbook and make sure that CheckboxChange appears in the list.  If it doesn't, you may have accidentally written the macro in the wrong project.

Comment: Most excellent example Dick Kusleika. The amount of control I now have over the checkbox is so helpful and a lot neater when compared to the 'ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add=' method I've been using. Big thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any events available with the Excel.Checkbox control. Try using the MSForms checkbox instead. You'll need a reference to 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library' - it's not redistributeable, but if you're using VBA, then that's fine.

You can then do something like this, and handle the event in the usual way:

```
''class level
Private WithEvents m_Checkbox as MSForms.CheckBox

Public Sub MakeCheckbox()
    Set m_Checkbox = Activesheet.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1")
End Sub

Private Sub m_Checkbox_Click()
    ''Do stuff
End Sub
```

Obviously, you'll only be able to handle a set number of checkboxes this way - I would recommend creating a class to hold each checkbox.