# Change Worksheet When a Cell Value and a Checkbox Change

Tags: excel, user-controls, vba

I have a Workbook with multiple Sheets. I have a menu page (Worksheet) with multiple user choices (Enter a new order, update an order, etc.) Each choice has a check box beside it and depending on which check box is checked, cells `F4:F21` change from `0` to `1` and, cell `B1` changes to the name of the Worksheet where I want to go. I have the following VBA in the Main Menu worksheet but when I click a check box, nothing happens. Any ideas why?

CODE

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 ClearMenuForm
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim sh As String
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F21")) Is Nothing Then
 sh = Cells(1, "B").Value
 Sheets(sh).Select
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Clicking a check box does not activate the event `Worksheet_Change` (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx)). That is why nothing happens.

Try changing one of the cells instead to see the effect.

What I think you want to do is assign an action to your Checkbox(es). You can do this in two ways:

1. Right clicking on the checkbox, and Assign Macro...

   [image]

   You have to create the associated macro, which will likely contain parts of the code that you already wrote, and/or calls to subs you have. You may bring the VBE (Alt+F11), insert a module in your VBA project, and write your `Sub`, e.g.,

   ```
   Sub CheckBox1_Click()
       MsgBox "Checkbox 1a has changed"
   End Sub
   ```
2. Via VBA (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007164/detecting-changes-to-checkboxes-via-vba)). With the sample code below, you would execute `InitCBs`, and that would associate `CheckBox1Change` with the checkbox (it actually assigns actions for both checkboxes in the figure; action for checkbox 2 is `CheckBox2Change`). You may also set `InitCBs` to be executed when opening the file.

   ```
   Sub CheckBox1Change()
       MsgBox "Checkbox 1b has changed"
   End Sub

   Sub InitCBs()
       Dim cb As CheckBox
       For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
         With cb
           Dim action As String
           'action = "CheckboxChange"
           action = Replace(cb.Name, " ", "") & "Change"
           .OnAction = action
         End With
       Next cb
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Interesting. I would have guessed that if it was a Forms checkbox with an associated cell, the Change event would happen when the cell changed from TRUE to FALSE, but no. +1

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `sh` as a `String`. Since there is no sheet named "1", for example, your code will generate a "Subscript out of Range" runtime error. Try changing `sh` to a `Long`.

```
Dim sh As Long
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and still nothing. It's like the macro isn't even running.