# Action when linked cell of option button changes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a problem with my **option buttons** linked cells. I'd like to load a macro whenever the value of the linked cell changes.
I tried two different methods, and none of them won't work when the button changes the value. If I type in a selected cell a value, my macros do load.

Here are my two techniques:

```
Private Cel_CONGESg As Byte
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Externe")

If Ws.Range("$I$12").Value <> Cel_CONGESg Then
    MsgBox "heheheheeheheheheee"
End If

Cel_CONGESg = Ws.Range("$I$12").Value

End Sub
```

The second method

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Dim CongesG
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set CongesG = Ws.Range("$I$12")

If Not Application.Intersect(CongesG, Range(target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
    If Ws.Range("$I$12").Value = 2 Or Ws.Range("$I$12").Value = 0 Then
        Ws.Range("$I$13").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            With Range("H12:L12").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlDot
                .Color = RGB(51, 63, 79)
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
    ElseIf Ws.Range("$I$12").Value = 1 Then
        Ws.Range("$I$13").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            With Range("H12:L12").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlNone
            End With
    End If 'I12 Congés
End If 'Application intersect CongesG
End Sub
```

Could you please help me understand what's the problem?

Thank you in advance. Have a great day.

Jean

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the full capabilities of the `Worksheet_Change` event, and `Target`, which is already defined as `Range`.

Try the code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim CongesG As Range

Set CongesG = Range("$I$12")

If Not Application.Intersect(CongesG, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case 2, 0
            Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            With Range("H12:L12").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlDot
                .Color = RGB(51, 63, 79)
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        Case 1
            Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            With Range("H12:L12").Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlNone
            End With
    End Select
End If 'Application intersect CongesG
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai and thank you for your time. Unfortunately, this code does not work... There is absolutely no effect on the sheet :( (I Copy/Pasted it completely to make sure). EDIT: When I modify the line manually (not with the option button), it does work. Same problem as before.

Comment: After further research, I think what I'd like to do is not possible... It seems calling a worksheet_change or a worksheet_calculate is not possible when the changing cell is changed by another action (CheckBox or Option Button). I may have to set a formula to my linkedcell (i.e. O12 : "=I12") and it'll work, or asign a macro to every option button. This last option does not apply when none of my optionbutton is activated (value = 0). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377911/change-worksheet-when-a-cell-value-and-a-checkbox-change)

Comment: Another topic about it, see [Neil Flaming's 2010-10-07 answer](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26526885/Run-code-when-cell-value-changes-as-a-result-of-an-action.html).

If you have any clue, let me know! :D