# VBA - Print lines to a .txt file

Tags: vba, excel

i'm having issues while printing values in a text file. Whenever I have a date or numbers, I get an "Error 13"... I guess it's linked to my variables but I can't understand where the problem is.

```
Sub SX_Externe_Generate_TXT()
Dim WsCib As Worksheet
Dim LastCol, LastRow, i, j As Byte

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Externe")
Set WsCib = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SX_Externe")
LastCol = WsCib.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
LastRow = WsCib.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

WsCib.Activate

Open "C:\Users\xizx692\Desktop\SX_Externe_Temp.txt" For Output As #1  'Tu crées le fichier text

i = 1

For i = 1 To LastRow
j = 1
    For j = 1 To LastCol
        Print #1, WsCib.Cells(i, j).Value + ";"; 'Séparateur = ;
    Next j
    Print #1, WsCib.Cells(i, j + 1).Value 'pas de séparateur (Saut de ligne)
Next i

Close #1

Ws.Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

The error comes at this line **Print #1, WsCib.Cells(i, j).Value + ";"; 'Séparateur = ;** whenever the cells(i,j).value is a Date or a Number format.

Thanks for your help in advance.

BR,

Jean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Print #1, WsCib.Cells(i, j).Value + ";"; 'Séparateur = ;
> ```

The concatenation operator in VBA is `&`, **not** `+`. The latter works sometimes if both operands are strings.

**number + string raises runtime error 13** unless the string is convertible to a number, but VBA will never convert the number to a string when `+` is used, it will only attempt arithmetic addition in this case.

```
Print #1, WsCib.Cells(i, j).Value & ";";  'Séparateur = 
'                                ^^^
```

This will solve the issue at hand, but there are a few other things that should be changed.

- `Dim LastCol, LastRow, i, j As Byte` this statement declares j as Byte and all others as Variant. Dim them all, and use long instead of Byte because Long should  always be your natural choice for integer variables, unless when there's a specific reason.

  ```
        `Dim LastCol as Long, LastRow As Long, i as Long, j As Long`
  ```
- `i=1` and `j=1` are superfluous, let the `For` statement do the initialization job
- The statement `Print #1, WsCib.Cells(i, j + 1).Value` is also superfluous since that cell is blank. To print  an empty line, simply `Print #1, ""`. Although it does the same, but it's beter for *readability* of your code.

Comment: Ash, thanks a lot for your answer. It helps me solving my issue and moreover: it teaches me great stuff. The reason why I used "Bytes" is because I know there will be less than 250 lines and I thought my code will go faster... Shame on me? I did not know the j and i would go back to "1" at the end of the loop, that's why I wanted to force j=1! Would you like participating to another question I asked? [Go here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44592776/action-when-linked-cell-of-option-button-changes/44593266#44593266) if yes! **Gotta solve them all ;D**

Comment: Thought, why defining LastCol, LastRow and i as Variant? Thx!

Comment: @Jean-FIC I meant that your initial statement declared them as Variant, not as Byte. Use `Long` for all your integer variables because it is 32 bits so it will be fastest and less exposed to overflow. The only place where you would think of `Integer` or `Byte` is when you have *huge arrays* that may cause memory issues.