# Trying to make a checkbox hide all rows where a cell in that row reads a specific value

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to make a checkbox to hide all rows where a cell in that row reads a specific value.

I've assigned the following VBA script to it:

```
Sub Hide_Rows_Containing_Value()

    If CheckBox1 = True Then

        Dim c As Range

        For Each c In Range("C2:C100").Cells
            If c.Value = "Closed" Then
                c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

And an inverse script assigned to it to unhide those columns when the box was unticked.

However this doesn't seem to work, does anyone have any ideas where I've gone wrong?

Comment: With what we see of your code, it will look at the check box when you run it, but not on a change in the checkbox's value. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007164/detecting-changes-to-checkboxes-via-vba

Comment: What is not working? You’ve assigned it to what? (what is the procedure name that calls this sub). Is the checkbox placed on the sheet or on a UserForm? What is the sheet name?

Answer (score 0):

If a CheckBox named `"CheckBox1"` is placed on **`Sheet1`**, use this code in Sheet1 module

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheet1
        For Each c In .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            If IsError(c) Then c.Value2 = "Closed"  'Hides errors as well
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = (c.Value = "Closed" And .CheckBox1.Value)
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

This will hide or unhide rows based on cells in column `C` containing the word `"Closed"` and the CheckBox being selected or not